# My data is being written to Firebase database but i can't read it why?

Tags: json, database, macos, swift, firebase

I'm new to swift and databases. All I'm trying to do is read from my firebase database. I'm using the example code provided here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html. 
I'm calling this from my viewcontroller.swift file in override func viewDidLoad(){}

```
func getRootRef(){
        // Read data and react to changes
        println("entered getRootRef")
        myRootRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            println("value1")
            println(String(stringInterpolationSegment: snapshot.value))
            println("value2")
            }, withCancelBlock: { error in
                println(error.description)
                println("error")
        })
        println("left getRootRef")
}
```

Output:

```
entered getRootRef
left getRootRef
ViewController3
ViewController4
value1
(Function)
value2
```

I do not understand why "(Function)" is printing out instead of my data. both read and write permission are set to true. I am making a Mac app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code sample doesn't give enough info as to what you want to do - however, assuming you want to print out the contents of the myRootRef node...

I believe that in Swift, FDataSnapshot.value is considered optional - it could contain a value or it could be nil. Therefore we need to unwrap the value:

```
myRootRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in     
   println( snapshot.value()! )          
})
```

The ! is a forced unwrap of the variable so it must contain a value. It should be checked for nil before printing or else it would cause a runtime error.

This may be safer

```
myRootRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    if let value: AnyObject = snapshot.value() {
        println(value)
    }  
})
```

Note that snapshot.value could contain one of a number of different objects: Data types returned: * NSDictionary * NSArray * NSNumber (also includes booleans) * NSString